# Glass showing gray spots

Tags: glass

i am following Andrew's doughnut series but when going into rendering mode or rendering the image of the glass cup it shows gray opaque spots i tried to recalculate Normals with shift+N and alt+N and none worked [image: the spots are marked in red]

thanks in advance

Comment: Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces. Try increasing Transmission/transparent

Comment: i has tried i cranked it up to a crazy 213 for transmision and 299 for transperant and 67 totall still the same